# Get signature bytes from V,R,S (ECDSA) using Solidity

Tags: solidity, signature, ecdsa

How do I get the signature bytes from V, R, S?
Here is what I have tried:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

import {Test} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {console2} from "forge-std/console2.sol";
import "openzeppelin/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";

library Signature {
    error InvalidSignature();

    function toVRS(bytes memory signature)
        internal
        pure
        returns (
            uint8 v,
            bytes32 r,
            bytes32 s
        )
    {
        if (signature.length == 65) {
            // ecrecover takes the signature parameters,
            // and the only way to get them currently is to use assembly.
            /// @solidity memory-safe-assembly
            assembly {
                r := mload(add(signature, 0x20))
                s := mload(add(signature, 0x40))
                v := byte(0, mload(add(signature, 0x60)))
            }
        } else {
            revert InvalidSignature();
        }
    }

    function fromVRS(
        uint8 v,
        bytes32 r,
        bytes32 s
    ) internal pure returns (bytes memory) {
        // v ++ (length(r) + 0x80 ) ++ r ++ (length(s) + 0x80) ++ s
        // v ++ r ++ s
        return abi.encodePacked(v, r, s);
    }
}

contract SignTest is Test {
    using ECDSA for bytes32;

    uint256 private immutable alicePk = 1;
    uint256 private immutable bobPk = 2;
    address private immutable alice = vm.addr(1);
    address private immutable bob = vm.addr(2);

    function setUp() public {}


    function testSignature() public {
        bytes32 hash = keccak256("signed by Alice");
        (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = vm.sign(alicePk, hash);
        address signer = ecrecover(hash, v, r, s);
        assertEq(alice, signer);

        bytes memory signature = Signature.fromVRS(v, r, s);
        (uint8 v1, bytes32 r1, bytes32 s1) = Signature.toVRS(signature);
        signer = ecrecover(hash, v1, r1, s1);
        assertEq(alice, signer);
    }

    function testRecoverVRS() public {
        bytes32 h = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(uint256(1), "whatever"));
        (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = vm.sign(alicePk, h);
        bytes memory signature = Signature.fromVRS(v, r, s);
        console2.log("signature length: %d", signature.length);
        (uint8 v1, bytes32 r1, bytes32 s1) = Signature.toVRS(signature);

        assertEq(v, v1);
        assertEq(r, r1);
        assertEq(s, s1);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work (tests fail).
Ideally, I'd love to keep the signature as `v,r,s`, but I want `bytes` for testing. I'm using foundry and I want to write a test for a function that takes `bytes memory` signature (in solidity).

Is there a function `v,r,s -> bytes`?

Comment: Can you try `return abi.encodePacked(r, s, v);` in function fromVRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @0xSanson mentioned in the comment above it should be `abi.encodePackaged(r, s, v)`. In the same order in which the data is read:

```
assembly {
    r := mload(add(signature, 0x20))
    s := mload(add(signature, 0x40))
    v := byte(0, mload(add(signature, 0x60)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Nevermind! I was encoding as `v`, `r`, `s` when it should have been `r`, `s`, `v` - Fixed that and it works perfectly.

I'm trying this as well, but it seems like when `ECDSA.tryRecover(bytes32 hash, bytes memory signature)` splits the sig back out into `v`, `r`, `s`, it is off by two digits.

domainTypedMessage: `0x81ecaf5bca8e50573e0183ad582d6b6426bd988c9c7fd40c529bea86232136c8`
PrivateKey doing signing: `0xdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef`

Signature (uint8, bytes32, bytes32):

```
v: 28
r: 0x4509ccf4268a2473492289ad0570117607db35455b8da02047c32921c7fd9d23
s: 0x74d70e4a1e9f0a465352c3394244c980441aba26b8909e100bae35970081ddff
```

abiEncodePackedSig (uint8,bytes32,bytes32 ==> bytes):

```
0x1c4509ccf4268a2473492289ad0570117607db35455b8da02047c32921c7fd9d2374d70e4a1e9f0a465352c3394244c980441aba26b8909e100bae35970081ddff
```

But when following the trace to the values input to `ECDSA.tryRecover(hash,v,r,s)`, I'm seeing this:

```
bytes32 hash: 0x81ecaf5bca8e50573e0183ad582d6b6426bd988c9c7fd40c529bea86232136c8
v: 255
r: 12786739849059462053674000992243531224588822583476003318711349217042056609181
s: 16037388220638135921918834900424162121165685228342423020224374679854836122077
```

When I convert those back to hexadecimal using [this](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html), this is what I get:

```
v: FF
r: 1C4509CCF4268A2473492289AD0570117607DB35455B8DA02047C32921C7FD9D
s: 2374D70E4A1E9F0A465352C3394244C980441ABA26B8909E100BAE35970081DD
```

We can see that 0x4509 is the first portion of the `r`, but it's keeping a `1C` in there for some reason. Same goes for `s` where the first two digits are `23` when it should be the `74`